# Java - else in the loop statement keeps executing

Tags: java, if-statement

this has me stumped. Im using a loop to go through an array and then using ifs/else to find whether it meets the criteria. However the else statement keeps being executed even though an if is being executed aswell. Probably something really basic im missing. I need to check in the if statements twice as the user is entering a genre aswell as the item in the array meets that genre too.

cheers

```
  for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
  {
     //RentalMovie movie = movies[i];

     if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("action") && movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";
     }
     else if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("childrens") && movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";         
     }
     else if (movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("drama") && movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";            
     }
     else
     {
        genreList += "- No rental movies were found for the genre: " + genreID; 
     } 

  }
```

Comment: Do you mean the first if statement executes (for example), but the elses thereafter do as well, for the same movie? Also can you please provide sample input and its respective output?

Comment: I think you wanted to do `movies[i].getMovieID().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID)` instead of `movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID)` because as it is, your code compares the same `String` - the one returned by `getMovieGenere()` - with two other `String`s (the `String` literal and `genreID`) that doesn't seem right.

Comment: You could also try a debugger (or at least a logger) to inspect your variables. If the `else` keeps getting executed then it is safe to assume that your `if`(s) aren't evaluating to `true`.

Comment: You're checking `&& movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID)`  in every case -- pull that out into a separate check and then see whether that part of the condition is failing or if it's the other check (or both).

Comment: I doubt your belief that an "if" is executed *and* the "else" is executed. More likely, the "else" *only* is being executed.

Comment: all the ifs if the evaluate to true get executed, aswell as the final else. Its checking twice for the user input(genreID) to equal and that the genre on the array is aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you mean is that you have some entries in the array that do match your search condition, and others that don't.  For each match, the appropriate `if` clause is executing, but for each non-match, the `else` is executing.

Since the action in the else is to add a message indicating that **no** matches were found, you probably don't want to add that every time a single non-match is found.  Rather, you want to do it once, after the loop, if no matches at all were found.  This might look like:

```
String genreList = "";

for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
  {
     if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("action") && movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";
     }
     else if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("childrens") && movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";         
     }
     else if (movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("drama") && movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";            
     }
     else
     {
     } 

  }

if (genreList.equals(""))
{
  genreList = "No rental movies were found for the genre: " + genreID;
}
```

P.S. I don't understand at all why you are checking the genre for each movie against both `genreID` and a hardcoded value before accepting it.  Are there other genres that exist in the list but you don't want a user to be able to search for?  That's the only way it seems to make sense, but that doesn't seem like a very sensible requirement.

Comment: the genrelist wont be an empty string, so say they put in something like romance, it should come with an error

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that the `if` statement is not being evaluated correctly. This is what I would try:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
  {
     //RentalMovie movie = movies[i];

     if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("action") && movies[i].getMovieGenreID().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";
     }
     else if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("childrens") && movies[i].getMovieGenreID().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";         
     }
     else if (movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("drama") && movies[i].getMovieGenreID().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";            
     }
     else
     {
        genreList += "- No rental movies were found for the genre: " + genreID; 
     } 

  }
```

The other thing I would try is to get rid of some of the code, ie:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
  {
     //RentalMovie movie = movies[i];

     if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("action"))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";
     }
     else if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("childrens"))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";         
     }
     else if (movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("drama"))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";            
     }
     else
     {
        genreList += "- No rental movies were found for the genres action, childrens, or drama -";
     } 

  }
```

The third thing I would suggest would be to try this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
  {
     //RentalMovie movie = movies[i];

     if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("action") || movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(genreID))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";
     }
     else if(movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("childrens"))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";         
     }
     else if (movies[i].getMovieGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("drama"))
     {
        genreList += movies[i].getMovieID() + " - " + movies[i].getMovieTitle() + "[" + movies[i].getMediaType() + "]\n";            
     }
     else
     {
        genreList += "- No rental movies were found for the genre: " + genreID; 
     } 

  }
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input. The ifs and elseifs are executing then the else is still executing even though the Ifs else/ifs are evaluating to true.

if i take out the second validation it has nothing to compare itself to hence all the Ifs get run.

sorry didnt ,emtion that genreID is a user input

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping through it with a debugger and you can watch the state of the variables as you go.